# How to catch an SVG parsing error?

Tags: javascript, svg, qunit

I'm trying to write a unit test (using **qunit**) for my code that generates an SVG path as a string. One of the test should be whether that thing is actually valid SVG at all.

In the Chrome browser console, it's easy to test just by doing this:

```
$("<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"><path d=\"asdsdsadas\" /></svg>")
```

This will fail with an appropriate error message:

> Error: Invalid value for  attribute d="asdsdsadas"

However, it also returns the invalid document, same as if it would have been ok.

When I run this code in `qunit`, the error is printed into the browser console, but the unit test still succeeds, since it's not actually an exception. I also had no success trying to catch it.

I've tried overriding `console.error`, but apparently this error originates on a deeper level that doesn't care about JavaScript trickery.

Does anybody know how to properly recognize this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal way to catch an svg parsing error from a string is to use a `DOMParser()` object.

If you do pass an invalid string to the `parseFromString()` method, then the DOMParser will return an error document.

```js
var invalidMarkup = "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"><path d\"M0,0\" /></svg>";
var oParser = new DOMParser();
var doc = oParser.parseFromString(invalidMarkup, 'image/svg+xml');

var failed = doc.documentElement.nodeName.indexOf('parsererror')>-1;

if(failed){
  snippet.log('failed to load the doc : '+doc.documentElement.nodeName);
  }
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

But the markup you gave in the question is valid svg+xml markup.
Parsers won't complain about it.

```js
var yourMarkup = "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"><path d=\"asdsdsadas\" /></svg>";
var oParser = new DOMParser();
var doc = oParser.parseFromString(yourMarkup, 'image/svg+xml');

var failed = doc.documentElement.nodeName.indexOf('parsererror') > -1;

if (failed) {
  snippet.log('failed to load the doc : ' + doc.documentElement.nodeName);
} else {
  snippet.log('success');
}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

What Chrome console does tell you is that it couldn't draw the whole segments contained in the `d` attribute of your `<path>`.

[Per specs](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/paths.html#PathDataErrorHandling),

> The general rule for error handling in path data is that the SVG user
>   agent shall render a ‘path’ element up to (but not including) the path
>   command containing the first error in the path data specification.

So in your exact case, nothing will be rendered, but no error will thrown either.

The only way to detect such error programmatically, would be to get your `path.pathSegList.length` and check that it corresponds to the number of segments you added into this attribute.

But IMO, you should test your values directly while generating it.

Comment: The point of a black box test is that I only check the output values without getting into the way the processing happens.

Anyways, pathSegList is deprecated in Chrome, but this lead me to their polyfill replacement algorithm, which allows me to achieve my goal. Thank you, I didn't think of just counting the number of path elements!